# 'Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0' after uploading file to FTP

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, permissions

Every time I edit a file (in this case a PHP file) and upload it via FTP to my VPS, via the user 'xtreme', the file, when accessed, outputs the following:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/foo/www/bar/ul.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Entering `chmod -R 2770 /home/foo` via SSH fixes the problem, but it's not very practical at all. I have to do that every time I edit the file.

I have Googled and searched Server Fault to no avail. Can somebody explain how to fix this?

EDIT: After setting permissions to 755:

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 xtreme www-data 4096 May  4 05:38 .
drwxr-sr-x 4 xtreme www-data 4096 May  2 17:50 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xtreme www-data    0 May  2 17:11 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xtreme www-data 1849 May  4 05:38 ul.php
```

After uploading file to FTP:

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 xtreme www-data 4096 May  4 05:41 .
drwxr-sr-x 4 xtreme www-data 4096 May  2 17:50 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xtreme www-data    0 May  2 17:11 index.php
-rwx------ 1 xtreme www-data 1849 May  4 05:41 ul.php
```

So, after uploading the file the permissions are set to what I assume is 0700?

Comment: What FTP server are you using?

Comment: vsftpd, and if it matters, I'm using Rapid PHP's built in FTP client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I just edited my vsftpd settings like so:

```
chown_upload_mode=0755
file_open_mode=0755
local_umask=000
```